# Possible to include anything other than Detail records in a Report CSV Export?

Tags: reporting

I have a requirement to provide several CSV downloads from a partner portal.  Several of these are fairly short and summarize a lot of detail; I will generate these using VF & Apex.  A couple, however, are essential detail dumps, and have the potential to get pretty large.  Using a custom report type to customize column headers, I have designed a report that produces the correct csv when exported, and I can generate a direct link to the report's csv download using a combination of [url params to specify the export](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/custom-link-to-download-export-report-in-single-click) and [url params to specify filter criteria](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/673/populating-filter-criteria-and-custom-filter-logic-on-reports-through-url).

However, I have an additional requirement to include what is essentially "header" information at the top of the file, containing a few values based of the filter params.  I have yet to find any way to include anything in an exported report except detail rows.  Am I missing anything?  This doesn't have to be complex - I'd even be happy pre-calculating the extra values and passing it in as a param, but I need it to be an additional row, not additional columns on every row.  Is this possible?  I've considered adapting @eyescream's [brilliant method of attaching reports to email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/scheduled-reports-as-attachment/4688#4688) and writing an apex method to grab the report and add the extra line on the fly, but I'm concerned that I might exceed the heap size limit (which is why I went with a report in the first place).

Additional Details:  The custom report type relates three objects (A with at least one B, B with at least one C), and the report itself is a basic tabular format report.